# get data from a particular item on clicking

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6

I have a list of items stored in an array named "permissions" and the data is like this 
[image: pic]

When i click on the particular item i want only the particular items data to be displayed.

**component.html**

```
<a class="selected"  (click)="displayPermission()">click</a>
```

**component.ts**

```
displayPermission(){
//what will be the logic inside here;
console.log(logic needed); 
}
```

Comment: how do you display the items , ngFor ?

Comment: yes by using ngFor

Comment: This is the basics of coding ... I don't want to sound mean, but you should really work on your coding skills before asking framework-specific questions (and use a framework). Also, if you don't know, Angular provides a [full documentation](https://angular.io/guide/displaying-data) that can help you learn this kind of things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> component.html

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of permissions">
    <a class="selected"  (click)="displayPermission(item)">click</a>    
    <ng-container *ngIf="item.open">
        <!-- html for item details -->
        <p>{{item.group_id}}<p>
    </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

> component.ts

```
displayPermission(item){
    item.open = !item.open;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

*template*

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
  <a class="selected"  (click)="displayPermission(item)">click</a>
</div>
```

*componenet*

```
displayPermission(data){
  consolelog(data);
  console.log(logic needed); 
}
```

Comment: in this case, you wont be able to modify the original array if you want in any case unless you search it in the array.

Comment: if the array contine object you can modify the object directly , if  the array has just  primative type you need index as @SarthakAggarwal answer

Answer (score 1):

You can display the data in .html using `*ngFor` directive which will iterate over your list of items on whose click you can call a function with the `index` of that particular item in array.

**.component.html**

```
permissions = [{},{},{}] 

showData(index){
  // Do anything with the selected item
  console.log(permissions[index]);
}
```

**.component.html**

```
<div *ngFor="let p of permissions;let i = index">
  <button (click)="showData(i)">Permission {{i}}</button>
</div>
```